# Final UIButton in a UITableViewCell is unmutable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView (and associated Cells) with a variable number of items.  Inside each cell are values associated with the object being displayed.  There is also a button allowing a user to state whether the task being displayed (from the object properties) is completed or not.  It is supposed to change color and become active.  This works, except for the final item on the list.  Here is the code that is not working:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TasksItem"];
    [BAPAppDelegate setBorder:[cell viewWithTag:300] withBorder:[BAPAppDelegate darkGreyColor]];
    [BAPAppDelegate setBorder:[cell viewWithTag:301] withBorder:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [BAPAppDelegate setBorder:[cell viewWithTag:1000] withBorder:[UIColor blackColor]];
    ServiceRequest *sr = (mListTasks)[indexPath.row];
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:110] setText:sr.vSRType];
    UILabel *smry = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:301];
    smry.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sr vMTSmry]];    // check if completed
    int cnt;
    int complete;
    UIButton* btn;
    cnt = [sr getBeforeRequired];
    complete = [sr getBeforeCompleted];
    markCompleteButton = YES;
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
    if (cnt > 0) {
        [btn setHidden:NO];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [btn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (complete < cnt) {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self markComplete:NO];
    } else {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    cnt = [sr getDuringRequired];
    complete = [sr getDuringCompleted];
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:121];
    if (cnt > 0) {
        [btn setHidden:NO];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [btn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (complete < cnt) {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self markComplete:NO];
    } else {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    cnt = [sr getAfterRequired];
    complete = [sr getAfterCompleted];
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:122];
    if (cnt > 0) {
        [btn setHidden:NO];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [btn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (complete < cnt) {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self markComplete:NO];
    } else {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    cnt = [sr getCheckRequired];
    complete = [sr getCheckCompleted];
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:123];
    if (complete < cnt) {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self markComplete:NO];
    } else {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    [btn setTag:indexPath.row + 1001];
    if (markCompleteButton) {
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor]];
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setEnabled:YES];
        [btn setTitle:@"YEP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"YEP %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    } else {
        [btn setEnabled:NO];
        NSLog(@"NOPE %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    }
    [cell prepareForReuse];
    return cell;
}
```

As expected, the log displays "YEP 8", but nothing about the button itself changes.  Other buttons earlier in the list display and perform their action as expected.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Need more context (more code) to help, but as a wild guess, it the 8th cell off screen? If so, I suspect it is being reused and it's state is not as you expect. Take a look at the UITableViewCell prepareForReuse method.

Comment: There's not much more code to add, frankly, it's a very dull implementation, which is why I'm so confused. It is, however, indeed below the fold so it does need to be scrolled to, vs. others that work correctly.  I will edit my code fragment to provide some additional context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subclassing UITableViewCell and connecting the UITableViewCell from my storyboard to my subclass, and then connecting the button's outlet to the subclass.  Additionally, I set the button's action to go to the subclass.

**TasksCell.h**

```
@protocol TasksCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
@end

@interface TasksCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<TasksCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

**TasksCell.m:**

```
#import "TasksCell.h"

@implementation TasksCell
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.delegate buttonPressed:sender];
}
@end
```

**TasksViewController.h**

```
#import "TasksCell.h"
```

**TasksViewController.m:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TasksCell *cell;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TasksItem"
                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [BAPAppDelegate setBorder:[cell viewWithTag:300] withBorder:[BAPAppDelegate darkGreyColor]];
    [BAPAppDelegate setBorder:[cell viewWithTag:301] withBorder:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [BAPAppDelegate setBorder:[cell viewWithTag:1000] withBorder:[UIColor blackColor]];
    ServiceRequest *sr = (mListTasks)[indexPath.row];
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:110] setText:sr.vSRType];
    UILabel *smry = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:301];
    smry.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sr vMTSmry]];    // check if completed
    int cnt;
    int complete;
    UIButton* btn;
    cnt = [sr getBeforeRequired];
    complete = [sr getBeforeCompleted];
    markCompleteButton = YES;
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:120];
    if (cnt > 0) {
        [btn setHidden:NO];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [btn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (complete < cnt) {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self markComplete:NO];
    } else {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    cnt = [sr getDuringRequired];
    complete = [sr getDuringCompleted];
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:121];
    if (cnt > 0) {
        [btn setHidden:NO];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [btn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (complete < cnt) {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self markComplete:NO];
    } else {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    cnt = [sr getAfterRequired];
    complete = [sr getAfterCompleted];
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:122];
    if (cnt > 0) {
        [btn setHidden:NO];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cnt] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [btn setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (complete < cnt) {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self markComplete:NO];
    } else {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    cnt = [sr getCheckRequired];
    complete = [sr getCheckCompleted];
    btn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:123];
    if (complete < cnt) {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aprsi_check_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self markComplete:NO];
    } else {
        [btn setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aprsi_check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [cell.button setTag:indexPath.row + 1001];
    if (markCompleteButton) {
        cell.button.backgroundColor = [BAPAppDelegate greenColor];
        [cell.button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.button setEnabled:YES];
        NSLog(@"YEP %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    } else {
        [cell.button setTitleColor:[BAPAppDelegate darkGreyColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [cell.button setBackgroundColor:[BAPAppDelegate lightGreyColor]];
        [cell.button setEnabled:NO];
        NSLog(@"NOPE %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    }
    [cell prepareForReuse];
    return cell;
}
```

Which allowed the button to work as expected, I kept the button delegate in the TasksViewController, but just as easily could move it to the subclass.  Hope this helps someone out!